# Xslt 1.0 : add months(integer) to date time format

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt. I have two inputs in an xml as 
input 1 is startDate in datetime format—2012-12-26T00:00:00
Input 2 is warrantyMonths in integer format —12 months
I want the output as endDate in dateTime format which will be startDate+warrantyMonths.

Request:

```
 <ass:FinancialInfo xmlns:ass="******">
        <ass:name>Test</ass:name>
        <ass:warrantyMonths>12</ass:warrantyMonths>
        <ass:startDate>2012-12-26T00:00:00</ass:startDate>
  </ass:FinancialInfo>
```

How can i do this in xslt 1.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your actual XML (or at least the relevant part) so we can see what it really looks like?

Comment: Thanks. updated my question with part of the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easy to do in XSLT 1.0. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:template name="add-months-to-dateTime">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>
    <xsl:param name="months-to-add"/>
    <!-- extract components -->
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($dateTime, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($dateTime, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($dateTime, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-after($dateTime, 'T')"/>
    <!-- calculate target year and month (using Knuth's corrected mod) -->
    <xsl:variable name="m11" select="$month + $months-to-add - 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + floor($m11 div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$m11 - 12 * floor($m11 div 12) + 1"/>
    <!-- calculate target day (clipped to last day of target month, excess days do not overflow) -->
    <xsl:variable name="cal" select="'312831303130313130313031'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="leap" select="not($y mod 4) and $y mod 100 or not($y mod 400)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month-length" select="substring($cal, 2 * ($m - 1) + 1, 2) + ($m = 2 and $leap)" /> 
    <xsl:variable name="d">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$day > $month-length">
                <xsl:value-of select="$month-length"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$time"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Example of call:

```
<xsl:template match="ass:FinancialInfo">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <ass:endDate>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-months-to-dateTime">
                <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="ass:startDate"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="months-to-add" select="ass:warrantyMonths"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </ass:endDate>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Worthy function sir, plus one.

Comment: Thanks so much Michael. I will try it

Comment: Thanks Michael. You are simply awesome. That xslt works. Can you please suggest me some good sources to learn xslt

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade to XSLT 2.0, consider whether you can use an implementation of the EXSLT dates-and-times module, see http://exslt.org/date/. You can download an implementation of this library at http://exslt.org/date/functions/add/date.add.template.xsl, and either just include it in your project, or extract the bits you need. The template named date:add should do what you need.

Comment: I will try the EXSLT if that is supported. But i use xslts for OSB 12c projects and that only supports xslt 1.0 :(